# exporting threejs ShaderMaterial as mtl file?

Tags: three.js, shader, mtl-file

Is there a way to export a general threejs shadermaterial of the type:

```
var the_material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( { uniforms: u, vertexShader: vs, fragmentShader: fs ,name:id} );
```

into a .mtl file ?

Answer (score 2):

An `.mtl` file can only represent specific classic material types, like "phong" or "lambert". See this document: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/mtl/. As a result, it is not possible to put arbitrary shader code into an `.mtl` file. To export an arbitrary shader, you'll very likely need to export the entire vertex+fragment shader (e.g. `.glsl`).

Comment: And also the associated uniform inputs if you end up with any?